# How to get Compile time warning on non aligned fields inside packed struct

Tags: gcc, clang, alignment

let's say we have this struct

```
 typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) A {
        uint8_t a;
        uint64_t b;
        
    }A_t;
```

we can see that b is not aligned since it starts from offset 1, What I want to do is to get a compile-time warning that this structure has fields that are not aligned inside it, is there any way to do it? I'm asking so since in my project we create a lot of packed structures(hardware) and we add reserved fields to force elignment on them.

I saw answers about run-time checks, or casting to a different pointer, but that's not what I'm looking for, simple as that, if I declare this struct and never use it I want to get a warning, What we currently do is adding static_assert on each field.